# Is there a minimum iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, sdk

I'm working on a iOS application and a friend told me that Apple has a minimum SDK requirement. Is that true? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's not minimum iOS SDK. but It's minimum deployment target. which
>   indicate minimum iOS version supported by your application. from that
>   onwards you must support you application.

Ex. if your app minimum deployment target is 7.0 then your application must run on iOS 7.0 to latest iOS SDK i.e iOS 9.2.

Comment: Althought true Apple has placed restriction on the Xcode and SDK used to submit app. To my knowledge is it iOS 8 SDK with Xcode 6, but I could be mistaking.